# What is the bind address used for when forwarding a port via SSH?

Tags: ssh, port, forwarding, tunneling

I have a brief understanding of port forwarding via SSH. So let's say I have a VNC server up and running at port `5901`. I pick up my laptop, go to work, then I want to connect to my server, but I want an encrypted connection, so I tunnel everything into an SSH connection as follows:

```
ssh -L 666:localhost:5901 user@home_ssh_server_address
```

I tell my VNC client to connect to `localhost:666`, and I'm good to go.

Now, reading through the SSH man page, I found that I can specify a so called bind address:

```
ssh -L [bind_address]:666:localhost:5901 user@home_ssh_server_address
```

Thats where my question comes in:

> What is that bind address good for?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is that bind address good for?

If you have multiple local IP addresses, you can choose one of them to bind the port to.